# spout's open() method is not getting called when the topology submitted to the remote cluster

Tags: java, redis, apache-storm

I am having one spout and one bolt in my topology. This topology is working fine in local mode. But when submitted the jar of topology to the remote cluster the spout's open method is not getting called. In open() method, I am creating a hash key to store data in redis database but I could not find the updated data in database.

sample code is:

```
public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context,
        SpoutOutputCollector collector) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("i am in open");
    Jedis js = new Jedis("127.0.0.1");
    js.hset("Spout1","FROMSPOUT1","i am in open");

    this.collector = collector;
}
```

Comment: Can you give little more context: A log file of the worker that is running spout, or supervisor log. Can you connect to Redis without using storm?

Comment: this is the error i got in supervisor.log file :                 2013-11-26 13:25:01 supervisor [INFO] 0dacde2b-86ae-4ca2-91c7-9b11589c6133 still hasn't started
2013-11-26 13:25:02 supervisor [INFO] Worker 0dacde2b-86ae-4ca2-91c7-9b11589c6133 failed to start
2013-11-26 13:25:02 supervisor [INFO] Shutting down and clearing state for id 0dacde2b-86ae-4ca2-91c7-9b11589c6133. Current supervisor time: 1385452502. State: :disallowed, Heartbeat: nil
2013-11-26 13:25:02 supervisor [INFO] Shutting down 57d5f5dc-de8a-4977-8f44-13e1fb6c2bd5:0dacde2b-86ae-4ca2-91c7-9b11589c6133

Comment: content of worker.log file is :                                  2013-11-26 13:11:04 ClientCnxn [INFO] Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x14293476bd2001b, negotiated timeout = 20000
2013-11-26 13:11:04 worker [ERROR] Error on initialization of server mk-worker
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jzmq in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1874)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1087)
 at org.zeromq.ZMQ.<clinit>(ZMQ.java:34)

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you posted in comment I can assume you don't have `JZMQ` installed

```
Error on initialization of server mk-worker java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jzmq in java.library.path
```

Try something similar to this:

```
 jzmq() {                                                                        
     JZMQ_DIR=$BASEDIR"/jzmq"                                                    
     JZMQ_REPO="https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq.git"                              
     JZMQ_COMMIT="e2dd66"                                                        


     git clone -q $JZMQ_REPO $JZMQ_DIR                                           


     echo                                                                        
     pushd $JZMQ_DIR                                                             
     git checkout $JZMQ_COMMIT                                                   
     ./autogen.sh                                                                
     ./configure --with-zeromq=/usr/local/lib                                    
     touch src/classdist_noinst.stamp                                            
     cd src                                                                      
     CLASSPATH=.:./.:$CLASSPATH javac -d . org/zeromq/ZMQ.java org/zeromq/ZMQException.java org/zeromq/ZMQQueue.java org/zeromq/ZMQForwarder.java org/zeromq/ZMQStreamer.java
     make && sudo make install                                                   
     popd                                                                        
     echo                                                                        
 }
```

Where `$BASEDIR` is the folder where you want to install it.

Comment: @Shyam B R could you please accept the answer if it solves your issue. This way it might be helpful for others having the same prob